# How to use DisplayNameFor with view model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Suppose that we have a model like this:

```
public class MyItem
{
    [DisplayName("TheTitle")]
    public string Title {get; set;}
}
```

In case of simple models in Edit/Details/Delete views, we can use @Html.DisplayNameFor like this:

```
@model MyItem; 

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title) //Result "TheTitle"
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
```

or in the list view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyItem>;

foreach (var myItem in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title) //Result "TheTitle". Seems the model is still MyItem, rather than Inemerable<MyItem>.
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
}
```

This makes it easier to change the title of the attributes on many views.

But what about complex view model such as:

```
public MyViewModel
{
    [DipslayName("Count")]
    int Count;
    IEnumerable<MyItem> MyItems;
}
```

In this case, how to display "TheTitle"?

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>;

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Count) //Result "TheCount".
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Count)

@foreach (var myItem in Model.MyItems)
{
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => ???) //How to display "TheTitle" here?
     @Html.EditorFor(model => ???) //Same question, I think.
}
```

I tried some hard code here (a string "@: TheTitle" instead of DisplayNameFor) but thought it's not a good practice.

Thanks and Merry Christmas.

Comment: You haven't flagged your `MyItems` with a `DisplayAattribute`

Comment: Would you please give an example of that? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a `DisplayAttribute` attribute on your model property like this:

```
public MyViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Some Items")]
    IEnumerable<MyItem> MyItems;
    int Count;
}
```

After that you can use the `DisplayFor` extension method in your view and it will output `Some Items`.

Comment: Ah, good idea for the "Count" attribute ( I did not know that DisplayName attribute can be used anywhere rather than Entity of EF only). But this cannnot resolve the problem of MyItems yet. I added some new code to make it clear and thanks again :)

Comment: Have you tried doing this in your `foreach` loop: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => myItem.Title)`

Comment: Yes. And in <td> of each myItem, it works. But what about the <th>? There is only one <th> and foreach cannot be used then. Anyway, thanks for your information :)